# Can I inherit the assembly version of my WPF project from another referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I've got a WPF application (i.e. solution) consisting of a couple of different projects. One of the projects is a library, and I set the version number in the "Assembly Information" dialog, which updates the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file. If I want to keep things in lock-step, I need to do this for both the shared library project, and the WPF project which utilizes it.

I am wondering if the main WPF project can inherit its assembly version number from the shared library assembly. Right now the end of that file looks something like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.3")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.3")]
```

Is there any way to update that to use some sort of binding, back to the other project?

Comment: you can *add as a Link* library project AssemblyInfo.cs to your WPF Application. That will solve versions problem. I have 9 projects in my solution and all of them uses just one same file AssemblyInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not technically inherit an assembly version. What you can do though, is to link a the assembly version file from another project. In the *Add Existing Item* to project dialog you can press the down arrow next to *Add* button and select *Add As Link*.

As a downside, you have to always keep both projects in the solution. Also, be careful with version controlled files.